# Android WebView JavaScript from assets

Tags: javascript, android, local, assets

How can I make JavaScript and images on my remote HTML page be loaded from assets folder (or just any local resource)?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Answer:

1. You MUST load the HTML into string:

```
private String readHtml(String remoteUrl) {
    String out = "";
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(remoteUrl);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            out += str;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

2. Load WebView with base URL:

```
String html = readHtml("http://mydomain.com/my.html");
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

In this particular case you should have all .js files you want to use on the page to reside somewhere under "assets" folder of project. For example:

```
/MyProject/assets/jquery.min.js
```

3. In your remote html page you have to load .js and .css files that reside in your application like:

```
<script src="file:///android_asset/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the same applies to all other local resources like images, etc. their path has to start with

```
file:///android_asset/
```

A WebView would first load the raw HTML you have provided as string, then pick .js, .css and other local resourses and then would load remote content.

Comment: Why should you have to provide the absolute path if you set the base path with `loadDataWithBaseURL`? Furthermore, it seems that this breaks in 4.1+. :(

Comment: This seems to work in 4.1+ for me, and is so far the only way I've been able to load HTML with javascript that isn't hardcoded into the assets folder.

Comment: If the html is already remote with no possibility to edit the program should identify these files and replace the string from the *String html*

Comment: In this solution if webpage contains images, then no images will be loaded.

Comment: How can we implement this on postURL method

Comment: Still can't load the JavaScript on the WebView using HTML. My `index.html` (which contains the reference to the `index.js` file) is located in the _asset/www/_ folder (same as where the `index.js` file is located). I am trying to convert my `index.html` to string but it doesn't seem like it's working. The return value of the `readHtml` is always `""`. What am I doing wrong ?!

Comment: If i put a .js file directly under assets (e.g. assets/index.js) it loads correctly, but if I put a folder e.g.  assets/js/index.js then it fails to load, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If dynamically creating your HTML and then using loadDataWithBaseURL make sure any local resources e.g. javascript in your assets folder are referred to in the HTML as file:/// (I Spent hours working this out)

Comment: can you please tell me in detail how to dynamically add (file://) path to .js after getting html as string.