# How do you load Javascript into android webview?

Tags: android, webview, loaddata

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="resource://jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I want to intercept the protocol(resource://) and manual load Javascript into the webview.
So I can store third party libs in android assets.

I tried override onLoadResource of WebViewClient and then use **webView.loadData(data, mimeType, encoding);**
But it didn't work because the app went into a endless loop.

Comment: Why not just use `file:///android_asset` URLs instead?

Comment: I'd suggest reading through the PhoneGap (Now Cordova) [source code](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android). They've been doing this for a while now.

Comment: @jamn224
I tested phonegap but it does't work.
I move the index.html to my web server and modify the script tag like this:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, and it works perfectly!
I have searched this question many times via google and stackoverflow but haven't got the right answer.
And finally my roommate made it happen with just the first trying.

[Android WebView Javascript from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414312/android-webview-javascript-from-assets)