# Where should I store local files for a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

Lets say I want to store a JavaScript file in my app for an Android WebView to use. Where should I put this file? My first though would be somewhere in the `assets` folder, but I am not too sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following link and explanations:

http://www.41post.com/3985/programming/android-loading-files-from-the-assets-and-raw-folders

> The `Assets` folder is an '***appendix' directory***. The `R class` does not
>   generate IDs for the files placed there, so its less compatible with
>   some Android classes and methods. Also, ***it’s much slower to access a
>   file inside it***, since you will need to get a handle to it based on a
>   String. **There is also a 1MB size limit for files placed inside the
>   Assets folder**, however some operations are more easily done by placing
>   files in this folder, like copying a database file to the system’s
>   memory. There’s no (easy) way to create an Android XML reference to
>   files inside the Assets folder.

There is also a `raw` folder you can even use that, but:

> it’s important to highlight the main differences between the raw
>   folder and the `Assets` folder. ***Since raw is a subfolder of Resources
>   (res)***, Android will automatically **generate an ID** for any file located
>   inside it. T**his ID is then stored an the R class that will act as a
>   reference to a file, meaning it can be easily accessed from other
>   Android classes and methods and even in Android XML files**.
>
> Using the
>   **automatically generated ID is the fastest way to have access to a file
>   in Android.**

For completing the answer, you can easily use `file:///android_asset/`

Have a look at this question:
[Android WebView Javascript from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414312/android-webview-javascript-from-assets)

Comment: You forget that a WebView can acces files in assets very easy with android_asset://myscript.js.

Comment: @greenapps - yeah well that question was already answered and that's because i didn't mention about it.btw, i've added an example with the question.Thank you for your attention and mentioning about it.