# creating C# xamarin.ios webview application

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am developing the iPhone app using `WebView` and need to use MVC razor view approach. How to include jQuery for the `WebView`?
Which version it supports?
What is the right location to store jQuery files in project?

What will be the code for this method

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    WebView.LoadHtmlString (page, NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleUrl);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I think most of your question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9432330/657390)