# Android webview is not displaying chart.js

Tags: javascript, android, chart.js

I am trying to implement chart.js inside webview but it is not working at all 
even after trying many solution.It is getting the html tags but not going inside  and .I am attaching the html file below for reference

```
  package com.androminor.chartdemo;

  import android.os.Build;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.webkit.WebSettings;
  import android.webkit.WebView;
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private WebView webView;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.webview);
           webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pie.html");
      }

**The corresponding html is given below:**
        <!doctype html>
        <html class="no-js" lang="">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    canvas {
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <h1>Chart.js Sample</h1>
    <script src ="test.js"></script>
    <script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
    <canvas id="countries" width="" height=""></canvas>



    <script>
    var pieData = [
    {
        value: 20,
        color:"#878BB6"
    },
    {
        value : 30,
        color : "#4ACAB4"
    },
    {
        value : 40,
        color : "#FF8153"
    },
    {
        value : 10,
        color : "#FFEA88"
    }
    ];
    var countries= document.getElementById("countries").getContext("2d");
    new Chart(countries).Pie(pieData);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9432330/4044380

Comment: i did follow the link you provide but there is a hurdle, i am not using   i am 
    not using and http link while defining the string.