# How to load a js file from assets into webview when loading html from assets?

Tags: android, html, webview

I want to load the HTML file which is having JS reference from Android Asset folder. When i open the HTML file in browser it loads properly with all JS reference. But when i load from Android JS files are not referring.
**Sample Code**

```
WebView web_view = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView); `web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;`
                string sampleHtmlData = "<html><head>" +
                "<script src=\"epub.min.js\"></script>" +
                "<script src=\"jquery-1.10.2.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>" +
                "<script>" +
                "var book = ePub(\"Azure_Cosmos_DB_and_DocumentDB_Succinctly/\");" +
                "$(document).ready(function(){  book.renderTo(\"area\"); });" +
                "</script>" +
                "</head><body> <div id=\"prev\" onclick=\"book.prevPage()\" style=\"font - size: 64px; cursor: pointer;\" class=\"arrow\">‹</div>" +
                "<div id =\"area\" style =\"height:500px;\" ></ div >" +
                "<div id = \"next\" onclick = \"book.nextPage()\" style = \"font-size: 64px;cursor:pointer;\" class=\"arrow\">›</div></body></html>";
                web_view.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/Sample/", sampleHtmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

I have tried to load using LoadUrl also.

```
web_view.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/Sample/index.html")
```

**File Path:**
Assets/Sample

Can anyone suggest me to load local Html file with corresponding JS files? EPUB js will be supported in Android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android WebView Javascript from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414312/android-webview-javascript-from-assets)

Comment: You may need to set `web_view.setDomStorageEnabled = true;` too.

Comment: I have enabled DomStorage also. Still not able to the JS. HTML file is loading. But corrspoding JS code is not working. I am referring Epub.js and using the epub method to load epub file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by enabling below properties.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JellyBean)
            {
                webView.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                webView.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            }
```

**Note**: Keep the required JS files directly into Assets folder instead of keeping inner folders to keep JS files

-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try this friend.

```
webView.loadData("Your HTML source", "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

webView.loadData() loads webpage source code directly into WebView

Please embed your JAVASCRIPT inside HTML

Answer (score 1):

Hello Try this example if it helps

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView view;
JSInterface api;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    api = new JSInterface();
    WebSettings asd = view.getSettings();

    asd.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.addJavascriptInterface(api, "api");

    String url = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
    view.loadUrl(url);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:api.getString(document.getElementsByClassName('txtTitle')[0].innerHTML)");
        }
    });
}

private class JSInterface {

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void getString(String str) {
        Log.d("STRING", str);
    }

}
}
```